# how to apply bootstrap jumbotron class on each resultset returned?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a java project where i am getting the rows from the result set object and printing it in table , now what i want is that every row which is retrieved from database should be shown in a seperate jumbotron(bootstrap class) box.

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Contents</th>
            <th>IP Address</th>
            <th>CreateDate</th>

            <th>TopicID</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="message">

            <tr>

                <td><c:out value="${message.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${message.title}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${message.username}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${message.contents}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${message.ip}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${message.createTime}" /></td>

                <td><c:out value="${message.topicid}" /></td>
                <!-- <td><a href="topicServlet?action=view">View</a></td>
                <td><a href="topicServlet?action=delete&topicId=<c:out value="${message.id}"/>">Delete</a></td>  -->

            </tr>

        </c:forEach>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And the problem is? You already seem to know how to loop, so all you need to do is forget about the table and its header, and replace each `tr`  by a jumbotron. containing the data displayed however you want to.

Comment: Thanks alot @JB Nizet for your reply. Yeah i was applying jumbotron class on whole table but now i removed <td> and printed each record in another <tr> row and it fixed the problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace each tr tag by a div class= jumbotron and add br tag at the end of each >/tr>.
It will show each record set in a seperate row of jumbotron.